# Retrieve Recycle Bin Size using c#

Tags: c#-4.0, recycle-bin, shell32.dll

I want to retrieve the Size of the Recycle Bin using c# windows application

I tried it with shell32.dll but it raises an exception

So any alternate or solution using shell32.dll will we acceptable

Comment: what have you tried ? please show some code... what exactly is the error messages/problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you tried shell32.dll but did you saw this: 
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/164491-working-with-the-windows-recycle-bin-with-c%23/